# NFS won't allow access to mounted media

Tags: network-shares, samba, nfs, sshfs

I'll explain it here, but I have [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=976568) problem, for which the solution that user received doesn't fix my problem satisfactorily (sshfs)

The problem is that I would like to share my /media folder over the network, so whenever I attach a drive on one desktop the other desktops/laptops lying around will be able to see that drive.

#### What I want

- Automatic mounting without password dialogues (stored plaintext credentials are okay)
- Share drives mounted on one computer with anyone on the network (or anyone who mounts and has correct credentials)
- Suggestions/solutions with respect to any of the below, or other methods.
- Linux server/linux client

#### What I've tried

- Samba
- sshfs
- nfs

#### Problems with each

With samba, the setup was lengthy and I've had hard to reproduce results depending on what I tweaked when and where. I've lately had trouble accounting for very basic user authentication and complaints of unknown parameters.

With sshfs I had everything work perfectly, but this is a multi-user system with multiple desktops. Each desktop has the same set of user accounts but there are different passwords for each desktop and the home folder is on a per computer basis. The system users are not the most computer literate and would be much more likely to stay with linux if things just work (like they *almost* do with nfs). Thus, having everyone prompted for an RSA key password on login so they can attach network drives is less than optimal. (RSA key or worse yet an ssh password for each computer based on which drive is mounting)

NFS *almost* works, everything can mount automatically and the correct folder will mount. According to the attached link, nfs doesn't allow mounted drives mounted in /media to be shared across the network as is. I've read that it is possible to share mounted drives on a per drive basis, but this doesn't account for when a new drive is plugged in on an individual desktop, and this is a must.

Any thoughts, ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention an "attached link" but there is no link.  What OS is the server, and what OS is the client?

Comment: The link is under the word "this" http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=976568  Linux server/linux client.